# Error when compiling java applications from command prompt

Tags: java

Recently, when trying to compile java programs from the command prompt, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

I have the latest versions of the JDK and JRE, and I still get the error.
Here is what I type in the command line:

```
C:\Java_Source_Codes>javac hi.java
```

Can anyone help?

(Here is my java code)

```
public class hi{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("hello, world!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues, Kumar mentioned the compilation issue, but that's not the immediate problem that's stopping you.

You have `JAVA_HOME` set to a Java Runtime environment, but are finding `javac` on the system `PATH`.  When this happens, you can call `javac` from the command line, but when `javac` detects the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable, it loads its libraries from a directory that doesn't include the "java tools", `tools.jar`.  The contents of "java tools" includes the classes that implement the compiler.

You probably have `JAVA_HOME` set to something like `/some/path/here/jre`.  Assuming that the `jre` directory is the embedded JRE shipped with your JDK, you probably should have set the `JAVA_HOME` to `/some/path/here`.

Comment: I did that, but now it says that javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @user1532256 That's because you either have a PATH entry that uses JAVA_HOME within it, and you didn't update the PATH entry to include the JDK bin directory (odds are is is somewhat mangled to accomodate the wrong JAVA_HOME setting) or because you attempted to follow multiple "suggestions" and managed to set your PATH incorrectly in some other manner.

Comment: OK... How do I set the JAVA_HOME path? I tried typing it into the cmd, followed by the path, but it just said about the batch file thing again, only this time with JAVA_HOME

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JAVA_HOME path".  There is a JAVA_HOME environmental variable, and a PATH environmental variable.  JAVA_HOME should point to the base directory of the installation, and PATH should be set to the same value as JAVA_HOME, with an additional "bin" directory added to it.  So if you installed Java in C:\java-1.6.23, then JAVA_HOME should be set to "C:\java-1.6.23" and PATH should contain an entry "C:\java.1.6.23\bin".

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your PATH variable set up with a path to Java tools needed for compilation.

You need to have these folders in Path system variable.

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin
```

Just replace `D:\Program Files\Java` with the folder you have installed Java on your computer.
Also, if you are using any other verion of JDK, replace `jdk1.6.0_32` with your own.

Comment: This isn't right, if the path was wrong, then he couldn't access `javac`.  It is that his JAVA_HOME doesn't point to a JDK, it probably points to the embedded JRE within the JDK, hence the ability to call `javac` and the inability for it to find the `tools.jar` which contains the compiler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Path to the bin directory of the jdk in your system..

Try typing `java -version` on the cmd to see if your Java path is properly set.

Mine is..

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
```

Comment: I guess the problem occurs earlier.

Comment: Sorry, that was me writing this question! It is the same in my program :)

Comment: The question was with javac HelloWorld.java when it was first posted

Comment: He's not finding the compiler class, so it's not getting anywhere near a naming convention issue, I'm afraid

Comment: I tried typing java -version but it came up with 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: that means your path is not properly set...if you are using windows. go to the Environment variable to set the path as i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is due to some issue with your PATH.

Quick guess is you have multiple version of java on your PATH

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem but found a simple solution that might work in your case too.

My problem was I simply made a new folder in c directory to save my *.java files (like a test folder) and set my PATH to ...jdk\bin folder.

When I try to compile in cmd I got the same error main class not found.

So i went to environment variable and in user variable, where I saw my CLASSPATH pointing to same folder. So I changed my CLASSPATH to folder having my files in my case C:\test and the problem was solved.

Hope this helps.